# How to Launch external local desktop Application from Angular APP like skype and teams

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to launch local desktop app like windows exe from the angular browser application. It's not happening. I want like where Skype and Teams app are provided in web application, will get a pop up 'do you want open desktop app? ' Like that. Similarly, I want to implement in my angular Application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your application needs to be [registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Then you could open your app using something like `<a href="myapp://`.